Can scoped style be achieved in React without using CSS modules?
My project uses CSS modules, but the output class name will be added with hash suffix. This is not wanted because I want to keep the class names semantic.
In Vue.js, scoped styled can be achieved by adding customized attribute. Is this kind of solution be found in React system?

React doesn't know or care about CSS modules. This depends on the toolchain you're using to bundle your app.
